# First column of Seq<int * string * int> to IEnumerable<int>

Tags: f#

I am using F#.  I have a `Seq<int * string * int>`.  I want to take the 1st column (the 1st int) and put it into a `Inenumerable<Int>`.  I want to do this because I am using the RDotNet and I want to call this function: `engine.CreateIntegerVector(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>);`

Comment: I've edited your code to highlight the code.  You may want to check it to ensure it still reflects your intent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An F# sequence is an IEnumerable so all you need to to is pick off the 1st element of the tuple.

This should work by using pattern matching fnc with a map:

```
let seqInt = yourSeq |> Seq.map (fun (v,_,_) -> v)
```

Comment: Not sure about fst

Type mismatch. Expecting a
    int * string * int -> 'a    
but given a
    int * string -> int    
The tuples have differing lengths of 3 and 2

Answer (score 0):

this is what I did, based on Tony's reply:

`let reportLength = engine.CreateIntegerVector(relevantContents |> Seq.map (fun (a,b,c) -> c))`

Comment: I think you mean (a,b,c) -> a?